# Shared resources in a vsix template project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, vsix, visual-studio-sdk

I created a solution with following structure

- Solution

  - Installer (VSIX)
  - Template One (sdk project)

    - One.vstemplate
  - Template Two (sdk project)
  - Shared

    - AssemblyInfo.cs

Now I want to link the AssemblyInfo.cs in the shared project to my vstemplates, because i want the same AssemblyInfo.cs in all my projects.
I dont want to have sevaral copies because of possible future developments.

Till now i tried to add the AssemblyInfo.cs as link, but the template build process still search in the project folder and does not find the file ([Add as link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714082%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)).
In addition i tried to reference the file using "\..\Shared", then i got a error out of root path.

One way I does not try is to use prebuild commands to copy the AssemblyInfo.cs to each project folder.

Has anybody an idea, tipp or solution for this situation?

---

I get a working version by using pre-build commands to copy the files from shared to the single templates.

Any other ideas how to solve this request?

---

Sorry for the late response.

I tried to reference the AssemblyInfo by adding following code to the vstemplate file

`<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">..\Shared\AssemblyInfo.cs</ProjectItem>`

My current solution is to add to each project a pre build command

```
copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)..\Shared\AssemblyInfo.cs" "$(ProjectDir)AssemblyInfo.cs"
```

Comment: please post some code, it may be a "solve-shot" but have you declared the path like this? string path= @"~/folder"

Comment: I will post some code when i am at home at my pc

Comment: Have you tried link as "Shared\AssemblyInfo.cs" ?